# Unable to get specific section detail to display modally with correct "section" content?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I'm trying to display content that has the following hierrachy. There are 3 sections;
"PreMeds", "Fluid Management" and "Airway"
under these sections, each has their own subsections such as
"PreMeds" -> "PreMeds", "Induction Agents", "Volatiles"
"Fluid Management" -> "Fluid Management", "Massive Blood Transfusion Protocol"
"Airway" -> "Airway Basics", "Airway Equipment" and "Simplified Difficult Airway Strategy"

I want each section to display using my "Section Card View" style, and on the first page in a navigation view list the content and then when user clicks a certain section navigates to that section that shows its own subsection and names and then when clicking a subsection, that specific content will display modally to show the content in a text view.

I've arranged the data into a main model that has the AnaesthesiaModel sections and then that model has an array of the subsection details, then that subsection detail gets passed and its names get shown. and then a specific section detail content is shown.
Currently it lists all the content as you would expect but when clicking finally it keeps showing either only a specific details content continously.

Here is my code for my models:

Anaesthesia Model

```
struct AnaesthesiaModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let details: [SectionDetail]
}

let sampleAnaesthesiaSections = [
    AnaesthesiaModel(name: "PreMeds", details: preMedsDetails),
    AnaesthesiaModel(name: "Fluid Management", details: fluidManagementDetails),
    AnaesthesiaModel(name: "Airway", details: airwayDetails)
]
```

Then subsection models

```
struct SectionDetail: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let content: String // You can represent each detail's content as a simple string for now
}

let preMedsDetails: [SectionDetail] = [
    SectionDetail(name: "PreMeds", content: """
preMed section content
"""),
    SectionDetail(name: "Induction Agents", content: """
    induction agent content
    """),
    SectionDetail(name: "Volatiles", content: """
Volatiles - MAC Values
Halothane 0.74
Isoflurane 1.2
Sevoflurane 2.0
Desflurane 6.0
""")
]

let fluidManagementDetails: [SectionDetail] = [
    SectionDetail(name: "Fluid Management", content: """
Volatiles - MAC Values
Halothane 0.74
Isoflurane 1.2
Sevoflurane 2.0
Desflurane 6.0
"""),
    SectionDetail(name: "Massive Blood Transfusion Protocol", content: """
massive blood transfusion protocol
""")
]

let airwayDetails: [SectionDetail] = [
    SectionDetail(name: "Airway Basics", content: """
Airway Basics
"""),
    SectionDetail(name: "Airway Equipment", content: """
Airway Equipment
"""),
    SectionDetail(name: "Simplified Difficult Airway Strategy", content: """
Simplified Difficult Airway Strategy
""")
]
```

Then my anesthesia view

```
struct AnaesthesiaView: View {

    let sections = sampleAnaesthesiaSections
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(sections) { section in
               
                NavigationLink {
                    SubsectionView(sectionDetails: section.details)
                    // destinationView(for: section)
                } label: {
                    SectionCardView(cardTitle: section.name, cardBackgroundColor: Color.green)
                }

            }
            .navigationTitle("Sections")
        }
    }
    
    // func destinationView(for section: AnaesthesiaModel) -> some View {
     //    return AnyView(SubsectionView(sectionDetails: section.details))
  //  }
    
}


struct AnaesthesiaView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnaesthesiaView()
    }
}
```

subsection view

```
let sectionDetails: [SectionDetail]
    
    @State private var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(sectionDetails) { detail in
            
            Button {
                showModal.toggle()
            } label: {
                SectionCardView(cardTitle: detail.name, cardBackgroundColor: Color.red)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
                DetailView(detailContent: detail)
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

detail view

```
struct DetailView: View {

    let detailContent: SectionDetail
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text(detailContent.content)
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle(detailContent.name)
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
//        DetailView(details: preMedsDetails, backgroundColor: Color("card2"))
        DetailView(detailContent: preMedsDetails[1])
    }
}
```

EDIT: Okay so now I realized that it had to do with presenting modally. I changed my detail detail view to simply show the string, then passed the selected subsection content into a new state. It works but only after clicking a few times. My guess is that its getting instantiated as the default then after clicking 1 or 2 times then the new content gets updated and shown. Why won't it update the first time?

> ```
> struct DetailView: View {
>
> let detailContent: String
>
> var body: some View {
>     ScrollView {
>         Text(detailContent)
>             .padding()
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
> static var previews: some View { //        DetailView(details: preMedsDetails, backgroundColor: Color("card2"))
> DetailView(detailContent: "Test")
> } }
>
> struct SubsectionView: View {
>
> ```
> let sectionDetails: [SectionDetail]
>
> @State private var showModal = false
> @State private var detailContent = ""
>
> var body: some View {
>     List(sectionDetails) { detail in
>          //            NavigationLink { //                DetailView(detailContent: detail) //            } label: { //
> ```
>
> Text(detail.name) //            }
>
> ```
>         Button {
>             self.detailContent = detail.content
>             showModal.toggle()
>             
>         } label: {
>             SectionCardView(cardTitle: detail.name, cardBackgroundColor: Color.red)
>         }
>         
>         
>         
>     }
>     .sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
>         DetailView(detailContent: detailContent)
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Okay so it seems to be that I was using present modally. And if using a navigationlink then it presents as expected. So I'll have to look into that as its the issue here. Does anyone have an answer they can link to?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out there is another .sheet option

sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)

and you use this to pass the item to the detailView
by first creating an setting a @state item detail variable
then setting it the the specific detail you want

then on .sheet you pass that specific item binding to the detail view...
SOLVED